# What does a greevil egg contain?

Tags: dota-2

What are the all of the different greevils that can hatch from a greevil egg?  What essence combinations are required for each, and is it even possible to still get them after Diretide has ended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://dota2traders.com/threads/how-to-make-greevils.24665/) is a great guide with images.

You can keep your essences in your inventory after diretide ends,but I don't know if you can trade them or what happens with your egg if you don't use it.

Red

- Ferocious Egg (Red type 1) : 1 Exort, Hatch outcome : Red Greevil Level 1
- Brutal Egg (Red type 2) : 2 Exort Essence, Hatch outcome : Red Greevil Level 2
- Merciless Egg (Red type 3) : 3 Exort Essence, Hatch outcome : Red Greevil Level 3

Yellow

- Anxious Egg (Yellow type 1) : 1 Wex, Hatch outcome : Yellow Greevil Level 1
- Eager Egg (Yellow type 2) : 2 Wex Essence, Hatch outcome : Yellow Greevil Level 2
- Spirited Egg (Yellow type 3) : 3 Wex Essence, Hatch outcome : Yellow Greevil Level 3

Blue

- Stubborn Egg (Blue type 1) : 1 Quas, Hatch outcome : Blue Greevil Level 1
- Resolute Egg (Blue type 2) : 2 Quas Essence, , Hatch outcome : Blue Greevil Level 2
- Determined Egg (Blue type 3) : 3 Quas Essence, Hatch outcome : Blue Greevil Level 3

Gren

- Covetous Egg (Green type 1) : 2 Quas/ 2 Wex, Hatch outcome : Green Greevil Level 2
- Greedy Egg (Green type 2) : 3 Quas/ 3 Wex, Hatch outcome : Green Greevil Level 3

Orange

- Ravenous Egg (Orange type 1) : 2 Exort / 2 Wex, Hatch outcome : Orange Greevil Level 2
- Voracious Egg (Orange type 2) : 3 Exort / 3 Wex, Hatch outcome : Orange Greevil Level 3

Purple

- Cruel Egg (Purple type 1) : 2 Exort / 2 Quas, Hatch outcome : Purple Greevil Level 2
- Wicked Egg (Purple type 2) : 3 Exort / 3 Quas, Hatch outcome : Purple Greevil Level 3

White

- Blessed Egg (White type 1) : 2 Quas/2 Wex/2 Exort, Hatch outcome : White Greevil Level 2
- Seraphic Egg (White type 2) : 3 Quas/3 Wex/ 3 Exort, Hatch outcome : White Greevil Level 3 (Source, Confirmed Thanks Treguard)

Black

- Dreaded Egg (Black type 1) : 1 Shadow Essence, Hatch outcome : Black Greevil Level 0

Natural

- Imbued Egg (Natural type 1): 1 essence of any type except shadow OR All other combinations, Hatch outcome : Normal Greevil Level 1 (Naked)